# dark theme for mendeley

Tags: gtk, theme

I am trying to use dark theme for mendeley, so that it matches rest of my gnome desktop. From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660529/force-mendeley-desktop-gtk-theme), I have done:

- Themes dir: `/opt/mendeleydesktop-1.18-linux-x86_64/share/themes`
- link Adwaita dark:

  ```
  # ll
  total 0  
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 31 Apr 18 10:22 Adwaita-dark -> /usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/
  ```
- Execute:

  ```
  GTK_DATA_PREFIX=/opt/mendeleydesktop-1.18-linux-x86_64/share/themes/Adwaita-dark /opt/mendeleydesktop-1.18-linux-x86_64/bin/mendeleydesktop
  ```

But it does not any change in theme:

Any clue how I can solve it?

I am using mendeley 1.18 with fedora 28 (gnome 3.28)

**UPDATE**

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
'Adwaita-dark'

GTK_DATA_PREFIX=/opt/mendeleydesktop-1.18-linux-x86_64 /opt/mendeleydesktop-1.18-linux-x86_64/bin/mendeleydesktop
```

and still does not make any change

Comment: I wrote the post on Ubuntu.SE; your theme link looks wrong. The target should be the desired theme (I assume `Adwaita-dark`), but the **name** of that link should be whatever theme you use currently (can be obtained with `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`). If the two match, then there is no need for any of this.

Comment: Also, the `GTK_DATA_PREFIX` should point to the Mendeley folder, not the theme itself.

Comment: @Sheljohn: can you kindly check the updated code?

Comment: You seem to have installed Mendeley system-wide. Instead of calling the binary in `/opt/...` you should call the one in `$HOME/.local/share`. That being said; if you would like to use the same theme for Mendeley as you use system-wide, none of this is required in Ubuntu. Not sure why this is not the case in Fedora. .. Have you tried rebooting? :)